# Administrator menu is disabled while i create article

Tags: joomla

I use Joomla (latest version). What i want to do:

```
1. Open article editing
2. Open other admin page in new tab
```

So i open article editing, click right on admin menu bar. Unfortunately it is not possible, because the menu is disabled while editing an article.

The workaround is to copy and paste url of admin page to a new tab. But this workaround and i need to navigate to the desired menu position in new tab.

Therefore i would like to be able to enable admin menu while editing article. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to `administrator > modules > mod_menu > tmpl` where you will have 3 files namely

1. `default.php` (ignore)
2. `default_disabled.php` (disabled menu files)
3. `default_enabled.php` (enabled menu files)

Then you need to copy everything from `default_enabled` to `default_disabled`. This will make the disabled menu the same as the enabled menu. Remember that this is core changes and it is not advised.

If the menu still looks transparent, you will just have to edit the css file of the template. Its CSS tag is `.disabled` and you will need to remove the `opacity`

Like layouts in the frontend you can override the output in the backend template. So make a new folder /administrator/templates/isis/html/mod_menu and add your changes here instead of directly in the modules folder. It is highly unlikely that these changes will be overwritten on upgrades. Of course, to be sure, you can make a copy of the isis-backend-template and do your edits here. More on template overrides [here](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core).